# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk app-pages-pages-module failed

Tags: angular

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk app-pages-pages-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost:4200/app-pages-pages-module.js)
onScriptComplete@http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:134:29
wrapFn@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9296:39
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8387:31
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:79507:33
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8386:60
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8159:47
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8462:34
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9708:14
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9734:27
```

I am getting above error while I run my Angular 7 app in Firefox otherwise, if I run in Chrome/IE or any other browser, everything is working find without any issue.

I tried to add global error handler to test if this is the error using

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any): void {
        const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk .* failed/;

        if (chunkFailedMessage.test(error.message)) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Initially I tried reloading instead of logging error on a console but firefox keep reloading website infinitely.

Is there any specific thing I have to consider? Or is there any other code you people want me to attach here to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

**EDIT:**
I'm using lazy loading modules. Here is the code for your reference if that is the culprit.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I am using Angular 7

After enabling router tracing I found below error message:

```
NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/pages/dashboard', error: Error: Loading chunk pages-pages-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost:4200/pages-pages-module.js))
```

Comment: This looks like you're serving the prod compilation on localhost. Does this also happen when you serve the dev compilation? If so, you might get more helpful error messages by running dev.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm serving in dev mode only. This is happening in both the modes i.e., prod and dev. Only Firefox is throwing this error and my home page is not navigating to my dashboard while, all other browsers are running app without any issue. My firefox version is 72.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: I'm assuming you're lazy loading a pages module in your app? Can you post how that's being done. I must say, it's intriguing that this is a FF only issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm using lazy loading.

Here is the routing configuration:
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
    },
.
.
.
}

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 7

Comment: Well that blows my v9 theory out of the water!

Comment: Yes. As per the error "...app-pages-pages-module failed" I can understand that something is preventing PagesModule to load but I am not getting any way to identify the error. In dev / prod mode same error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular 9, then you should upgrade to using `import()` syntax, as per the [upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3) and the [deprecated api docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax).

I'm not expecting this to fix the problem, but it's a good place to start.

Obviously this is irrelevant if you're < v9.